# How can I create a list containing the normalized element-by-element product of two given lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have to calculate:

[image]

How can I create such a sum? Do I have to set the factors of each term manually (one by one), like `G1 = 1, H1 = 1, G2  2, H2 = ...`.?

#### Update

[image]

Addtional Questions:

1. How can I store te results into another List? (In this example, the list `F`)
2. Sometimes, a variable turns blue and does not get calculated in expression. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create lists like this:

```
g = {1, 2, 3, 4}
h = {10, 20, 30, 40}
```

Then you can sum like this:

```
Sum[g[[i]] h[[i]], {i, Length[g]}]
```

or more nicely (Mathematica does element-wise operations automatically where applicable):

```
Total[g*h]
```

Additional question 1) You can use this feature to easily calculate a new list with the results, without using indices:

```
f = (g h)/Total[g h]

{1/30, 2/15, 3/10, 8/15}
```

If you want to use indices anyway, you can do it with `Table`:

```
f1 = Table[
  (g[[k]] h[[k]])/Sum[g[[i]] h[[i]], {i, Length[g]}],
  {k, Length[g]}]
```

Additional question 2) A blue variable means it is unbound to a value. The variable will be used as a symbol instead. Teal color means it is bound to a value via an enclosing function. In your example, `Sum` binds `i` to a value it fills in. A black variable has a globally assigned value.

Comment: How manipulate g[i], h[i] in basic calculations?(Not just in the `sum` function)

Comment: See my update please, thank you.

Comment: You can always change individual elements like this: `g[[1]] = 17`

Comment: I updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

Given a set of lists:

```
h = Table[RandomReal[{0, 30}], {7}]
g = Table[RandomReal[{17000, 20000}], {7}]

(* {22.7964, 26.9984, 0.971047, 4.21998, 21.7333, 20.8884, 14.155} *)
(* {18409.6, 17870.2, 19297.1, 19537.1, 19840.5, 19043.6, 17829.} *)
```

For alternatives to the fine answer by Justin, you can:

also use the [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dot.html) (a.k.a. Inner) product:

```
fList = g h/h.g

(* {0.201312, 0.231435, 0.00898861, 0.0395486, 0.206842, 0.190815, 0.121059} *)
```

or using [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html) explicitly gives the same List

```
fList = Table[h[[i]] g[[i]], {i, Length@h}]/h.g
```

If you want an actual [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html) to pick out individual parts of the list:

```
fFunction[i_] := h[[i]] g[[i]]/h.g
fFunction[1]

(* 0.201312 *)
```